# Highlight GOJS diagram node based on condition

Tags: gojs

I want to highlight a GOJS diagram node based on some condition using jquery. Suppose there is a variable status that has values `B`, `d`, or `p`. For `B` it should be red and for `d` it should be green. For `p` it should be yellow. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you provide us the code you've already tried, and highlight where it is you're running into a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting nodes is easy and there are a few examples [here](http://gojs.net/latest/intro/highlighting.html).

Otherwise this is just a question of filtering nodes. You'd most likely want to use [Diagram.findNodesByExample](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#findNodesByExample) to query for the nodes.

There's a search box in the [org chart static sample](http://gojs.net/latest/intro/highlighting.html) that gives an example of filtering nodes using `findNodesByExample`:

```
// create a case insensitive RegExp from what the user typed
var regex = new RegExp(input.value, "i");

...

// search four different data properties for the string, any of which may match for success
var results = myDiagram.findNodesByExample({ name: regex },
                                           { nation: regex },
                                           { title: regex },
                                           { headOf: regex });
```

See the documentation for [findNodesByExample](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#findNodesByExample) for more information.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, I am using  var alpha=mydiagram.findnodeBykey(-3); now i want to highlight the Node. please suggest

Comment: var alpha = myDiagramTouchPointGapAnalysis.findNodeForKey("-6");
                
                if (alpha != null) {
                    //alpha.isSelected = true;
                    
                    myDiagramTouchPointGapAnalysis.startTransaction("highlight");
                    alpha.isHighlighted = "true";
                    myDiagramTouchPointGapAnalysis.commitTransaction("highlight");
                 
                }

Comment: is there a way to highlight a node (change its color and then get back to previous color)

Comment: yes look at the first link I shared, on highlighting